# How to (really) set the focus to my application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm on Delphi 11 / Windows 11 and using the code below to force the focus to my application , when needed.

It works sometimes, but sometimes instead of setting the focus and bring my app Windows to front, Windows will only 'flash' my app icon on the taskbar.

Is there anything i could do to always achieve the task correctly ?

```
procedure setFocus;
var hand: thandle;
begin
 hand := GetForegroundWindow;
    if hand <> application.MainForm.Handle then
    begin
      try
        setForeGround(application.MainForm.Handle);
        application.showmainform := true;
      finally
      end;
end;
```

Comment: Your `try..finally` block, which has an empty `finally` clause, has no effect on your app whatsoever. Your program will be identical if you remove it.

Comment: Read the documentation for [`SetForegroundWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow), there is a lot of criteria that an application has to satisfy before it is allowed to put a window in the foreground.

Comment: Flashing the program's taskbar button is enough attention (whoring). Even that can be made more annoying via [`FlashWindowEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindowex). Imagine battling two programs for `if GetForegroundWindow() <> Handle then SetForegroundWindow( Handle )` over hours - why do you think your program is the only one wanting that?

Comment: Pro tip: Stop trying to fight the OS. It always wins. What you're trying to do is not allowed, and hasn't been for more than a decade. In addition, any application that behaves like that should be immediately uninstalled, and I'd make my best effort to blacklist it everywhere I could.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there anything [I] could do to always achieve the task correctly ?

No.

A modern operating system like Windows 11 won't allow an app to bring itself to the foreground without the user explicitly requesting it. The user is the one who gets to decide which apps to display on his or her own desktop and which app is at the foreground.

Indeed, this is very good. It is highly annoying when apps or dialogs just pop up without the user expecting them to do so.

**Mandatory reading:** [Foreground activation permission is like love: You can’t steal it, it has to be given to you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083) by Microsoft developer Raymond Chen.

Comment: Application being able to steal focus on their own isn't just annoying but also  presents a security risk. Let us say that you are at work and you are entering some sensitive information into your computer. If you are doing this for quite some time and if UI of the program you are entering this data is half decent you probably got so good at it so you can spend even a minute of time entering such data into computer without the need to direct your view to the monitor. So if in this time some application steals the focus you would end up entering this sensitive data to such application.

Comment: On the other hand you may want to provide your users with a software, that does not need to be the only one running on an expensive piece of hardware, and still be able to jump to the foreground to alert the user of for example a health threatening condition at one of their patients. And before you say: "Dedicated system" A hospital would need several of those in one room, that is just silly.

Comment: @Sherlock70 Alerting the user about some critical situation can be done by temporarily showing some notification window. You don't need to take the focus away. In fact you wouldn't want to. Let us take a look at another scenario. You have a doctor or nurse writing some report of last examination. And during this time your application takes focus in order to warn about critical condition of some patient. If you have your application set up so that pressing enter would close the notification you risk that your doctor might inadvertently close it before he can even read it just by wrong key press